# How to make two columns interconnected in openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, openpyxl

This is the code that I have so far:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

wb = Workbook()
dest_filename = 'file.xlsx'
ws = wb.active

start_col = 1
key_row = 1

logs = {
    'test1': [
        'com1', 'com2'
    ],
    'test2': [
        'com3', 'com4'
    ]
}

for l in logs:
  for a in logs.values():
    ws.cell(column=start_col + 1, row=key_row, value="{}".format(a))
    ws.cell(column=start_col, row=key_row, value="{}".format(l))
    key_row += 1


wb.save(filename=dest_filename)
```

this is the result I get:

[image]

I would like to see:

test1 | com1

test1 | com2

test2 | com3

test2 | com4

I have tried to iterate through the list but I had problems with formatting of the lists E.g.['com1', 'com2'].
I am using Python3 and openpyxl library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your for loop with :

```
for key, value in logs.items():
    for element in value:
        ws.cell(column=start_col, row=key_row, value="{}".format(key))
        ws.cell(column=start_col + 1, row=key_row, value="{}".format(element))
        key_row += 1
```

Comment: Thanks to @Hicham Zouarhi, he corrected one mistake that I did and added `logs.items()` in for loop

Comment: Ideally, with a dictionary you might well want to `sort()` the items before you start adding them.

Comment: @CharlieClark Thanks for sharing knowledge and you are right. Sorting of the dictionary will create a systematic ordered view but performance-wise both are the same. Hence, totally depends on requirement.

Comment: Sorting has nothing to do with performance but making sure the rows are written in the desired order.